# My code accidently deleted my 'song.mp3' file in Discord.py music bot

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, mp3

I was coding my discord bot and i was trying to make the bot not try to connect twice. Like, if it's already connected any user sends another '!play' command, i don't want it to error. But that's not my problem. I or my code accidently deleted my 'song.mp3' file. How do i get it back. I closed the pycharm so i can't do 'CRTL + Z'.

@client.command()

async def play(ctx, url: str):

```
song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
try:
    if song_there:
        os.remove("song.mp3")
except PermissionError:
    await ctx.send("Şimdi Çalan şarkının bitmesini bekleyin. Yada '!stop' komutunu kullanın.")
    return
# connects the voice channel
connected = ctx.author.voice
audio = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3")

voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='music')
if not discord.client.VoiceClient == None:  # None being the default value if the bot isnt in a channel (which is why the is_connected() is returning errors)
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    await ctx.send(f"Joined **{voiceChannel}**")
    discord.client.VoiceClient.play()
else:
    await ctx.send("I'm already connected!")



audio = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3")

# Dowloads the video from the link given

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
```

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a site where you ask these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for it in your Recycle Bin...